# How to configure SharePoint Search Service with local accounts?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell, enterprise-search, searchserviceapplication

I want to configure SharePoint Search Service with local accounts. The server is not connected with Active Directory. Also the SharePoint which is installed is a single server farm.

I tried to configure service both OOTB and Powershell but was getting below errors:

`1. The search service is not able to connect to the machine that hosts the administration component. Verify that the administration component 'f3148b8a-f8a9-4d97-ae41-fa083dcd351a' in search application 'Search Service Application' is in a good state and try again`

`2. Errors were encountered during the configuration of the Search Service Application.    System.ArgumentException: The SDDL string contains an invalid sid or a sid that cannot be translated.`

Please assist me to configure SharePoint Search Service with local accounts.

Answer (score 1):

You need read article: [SharePoint 2013: Service Accounts](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14500.sharepoint-2013-service-accounts.aspx)

**SP Search Service**

- Search Service Account
- Used for:

  - Windows user credentials for the SharePoint Search service
- Domain account

**SP Search Crawl**

- Default Content Access Account
- Used for:

  - For Search service application to crawl content.
- Domain account
- This account must have read access to external or secure content sources that SharePoint will be crawling.
- For SharePoint sites that are not part of the server farm, this account must explicitly be granted full read permissions to the web applications that host the sites